# How to write unit tests for document.URL in angular 5 spec

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine

i'm tring to mock document.URL = 'dashboard';
but getting as can't assign to url because its readonly property.
 While writing jasmine test cases
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hehCO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of accessing the `document` object directly you should be injecting its custom provider from `@angular/common`

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
```

then in your inject it in your constructor w/

```
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {}
```

you can then mock the document object and set `URL` property or any other property as needed. As you would any other service you inject into your components or services.

Comment: I'm trying to write jasmine tests @joshsommer

Comment: I'm aware of that, and the way you will be able to test this document is by mocking the object. But to do that you have to use dependency injection. When working with Angular you should never access the DOM directly.

Comment: after doing that getting same i have added the imports and initalized in the provide but getting same error 'can't assign readonly property'